# How to select a certain element in a div with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am scrapping a page, I need to select a certain element but there is multiple of them, this is how it is shown:

`<div data-v-513c5331="" class="flex text-xs border-b h-9">...</div>`

I know that I can use methods like:nth-child() and :nth-of-type() but they won't work because I have to select it from various pages, and they are not always in the same position.

The element has another element inside which has a text: "pinnacle", maybe using that text to refer to outer elements? Is that possible? Or any other way

```
for element in range(len(elements)):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='flex flex-col px-3 text-sm max-mm:px-0']")))

    div_matches = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="div[class='flex flex-col px-3 text-sm max-mm:px-0']")
    el = div_matches.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="div[class='flex items-center gap-1 my-1 align-center w-[100%]']")[element]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    el.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    bets_div = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="div[class='flex flex-col']")

    pinn_el = bets_div.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[text()='Pinnacle']//preceding::tagname[1]")
    print(pinn_el.text)

    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    time.sleep(3)
```

this is the page: https://www.oddsportal.com/football/england/premier-league/

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  Below XPATH expression will locate the preceding node of the element with the text **pinnacle**

**Syntax:**

```
//tagname[text()='pinnacle']//preceding::tagname[1]
```

**2.** Below XPATH expression will get the parent node of the desired element

```
(//tagname[text()='pinnacle']//..)[1]
```

Try using this XPATH and see if it locates the desired element.

Comment: Yes but when I use XPATH I always get the same error: 
```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()='Pinnacle']//preceding::tagname[1]"}
```
So I use CSS_SELECTOR in the file, is there anyway to do that with CSS SELECTOR?

Comment: Can you share your code? You can edit your question and update the code.

Comment: I updated it with the command that you suggested me

Comment: Same output with the update from above

Comment: `//*[text()='Pinnacle']//preceding::tagname[1]` - Here tagname is just the syntax. You need to replace it with the actual element's tag name.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application?

Comment: Okay, let me try it

Comment: The url of the web is https://www.oddsportal.com/football/england/premier-league/ i am trying to scrape the 1X2 odds for every match (only from pinnacle)

Comment: Not able to access this site, my laptop's firewalls are blocking it. Updated the URL in your question. Someone else will be able to help you hopefully.